# Jquerys .on('click') is only firing once then stops

Tags: jquery, click

I have searched on here and google for a solution to no avail, lots of similar posts but mostly people not using `.on()` or people missing end `});`'s etc

As in title I am using `.on('click')` and it will only call the function once then stops, if I use `.click()` it works as expected! I have checked in the console and it tells me the same.

I am using jQuery 1.9.1 with jQuery-ui 1.10.3 and am testing in chrome. Code below (I have omitted some code from the function and shortened some as I know it is not important);

html:

```
<section id="Cat_List">
    <ul> 
        <li><a href="?C=44834">Cat 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="?C=10908">Cat 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="?C=58202">Cat 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="?C=73689">Cat 4</a></li>
    </ul>        
</section>
```

Jquery:

```
$('#Cat_list ul').on('click', 'li a', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var href = this.href.split('?C=').pop();
    $('.loading').center('fixed').show();
    console.log(href[1]);
    $.ajax({
        url: Script,
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            Function: 'Cat',
            Cat: href[1]
        },
        cache: false,
        success: function (Data) {
            console.log(Data);
            /*Place data on second page*/
            $('#Cat_List').hide(500, function () {
                $('#Category_con').show(500);
            });
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

I have also tried changing to:

```
$(document).on('click','#Cat_List ul li a',function(e) {...
```

with no luck!

**Description of function:** 
as you can see it gets the category id of the clicked link in the UL fetches data and places onto the next "screen" then shows the next "screen". there is a back button that clears said screen and hides it then shows the category list again.

When the category list is unhidden no amount of clicking will fire the function!

Any ideas how to resolve?

Comment: You should show the code which restores the #Cat_List visibility. Also (might be a stupid comment showing I did not understand your code) I would avoid using 'Function' as a property name

Comment: okidoke will edit now; the Function was something i changed before pasting code just to show what that data was.

Comment: After firing `this.href.split( '?C=' ).pop()`, does the `href` in the DOM change?

Comment: I feel like there might be something else going on in your code.... http://jsfiddle.net/6ZVBt/

Comment: woah calm down, i pasted it from DW then tried formatting it but the tab button does not work properly, i did apologise for it. @Ascherer the js fiddle doesnt do anything, i presume because it doesnt have the page 2 html

Comment: AND, notice I removed the apology as not useful to the question. - same with all the "Thanks" type comments people post that should not be included in questions.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss There is a difference between being helpful, and being an ass. And slapppy-x If you check the console, it logs every time you click on a link

Comment: yes i see, i have edited it slightly, for some reason when my actual code fires the first time it grabs the full code after c= but on the fiddle it only grabs the last digit??  strange. would hiding a .on binded element destroy the on? i couldn't see why it would!

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss - Not everyone on SO is a native english speaker, relax.

Comment: You have a capital L in $('#Cat_List').show(500) ... I'm not saying that is the solution, but it sure prevents the thing from working properly...

Comment: No slappy, it doesnt. `.on()` stays with the dom. As long as you dont `destroy` the ul, it should keep firing

Comment: also in $('#Cat_List').show(500) ... (capital "L")

Comment: Thanks m7o I noticed this too and have already edited the fiddle; @Ascherer Thats what i thought thanks for your help i will have a review of my coding and see what i can come up with, i just dont understand how it fires the first time and not the second when it does it with your fiddle and when i use .click()

Comment: Checked that Data does not contain an element with id _Cat_list_, introducing duplicate ids in your DOM ?

Comment: @jbl i like your thinking but have checked and no duplicate ID's.

Comment: You should check the html that is added via your html() and append functions in firebug (or similar) to see if it's all correct - maybe there are some tags left open or some other corrupt html code inserted?

Answer (score 2):

I can't really test it with your code, but if I leave out the ajax and use correct IDs (you used a capital L in your JS (Cat_List), it works fine, see here:
http://jsfiddle.net/6ZVBt/

```
<section id="Cat_list">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="?C=44834">Cat 1</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="?C=10908">Cat 2</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="?C=58202">Cat 3</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="?C=73689">Cat 4</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
</section>
<section id="next_page">Next Page</section>
```

And the JS:

```
$('#Cat_list ul').on('click', 'li a', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var href = this.href.split('?C=').pop();
    console.log(href[1]);

    $('#Cat_list').hide(500, function () {
        $('#next_page').show(500);
    });
    return false;
});
$(document).on('click', '#next_page', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#next_page').hide(500, function () {
        $('#Cat_list').show(500);
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: AHA yes you are on to something here, if I comment out my ajax code it works fine for me! something is wrong with my ajax success code then!!! typically the bit i didn't think would matter so did not include. thanks

Comment: Added the success code block(used jsfiddle to tidy as suggested). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what `$('.loading').center('fixed').show();` is, but if it's an overlay, you didn't remove it!!

Comment: yeah it was removed in the /*Place data on second page*/ removed code area

Answer (score 0):

The problem stemmed from a little piece of code, rather embarrassingly, I had missed/forgot that I entered, to update jquery ui buttons.

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function(event, XMLHttpRequest, ajaxOptions) {
    $('button').button();
}).ready(function (){...
```

Not quite sure how this affected the .on from firing the second time but now removed it works as expected!

apologies for my stupidness! thanks for the help!